# Are there female minotaurs?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation, lore, races, minotaur

I wonder... Do the minotaurs in 4e have *females* of the species? Or do they just use humans to reproduce themselves? Or are they born in the void and come out of nowhere?

I've never seen any *female* minotaur in any of the illustrations...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Yes, there are female minotaurs.**

Nothing in the race description specifies that the race is male-only (the way satyrs are explicitly male-only and hamadryads are explicitly female-only), ergo there must be female minotaurs.

It's just a hypothesis, but based on the people I've known who've played minotaurs, the reason there are no images of female minotaurs is that very few people play them. Also, a quick [Google image search for 'female minotaur'](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1280&bih=936&q=female%20minotaur&oq=female%20minotaur&gs_l=img.3...1402.3295.0.3494.15.5.0.10.10.0.91.320.5.5.0...0.0...1ac.1.7.img.RXtbcVgM7_s) yielded a relatively low total number of images, and most of those were... fetish-oriented... rather than heroic. There aren't a lot of minotaur images in 4e books in the first place, and the artists probably opted for the traditional depiction.

Comment: Presumably it was difficult for Wizards to create a heroic-appearing opponent with 'Battle Udders' :P

Comment: Since you mention the traditional depiction its worth noting that in the original myths there was exactly one minotaur born of..unusual circumstances and it wasn't a race at all.

Answer (score 19):

Player's Handbook 3's race entry for Minotaur depicts one male and one female minotaur. Also note that they clearly specify male and female name examples.

Player's Handbook 3 p. 102 depicts a female minotaur in the Runepriest section.

Primal Power p. 109 Warden paragon path Emerald Guardian depicts a female minotaur.

Dragon Magazine #389 p.32 Winning Races: Minotaurs features a female minotaur. The article also discusses (albeit in passing) marriages between minotaurs.

Comment: Let's not forget Tome of Magic, which introduces the vestige of the original minotaur, which was a female albeit with a masculine appearance.